# UbuntuStudio 18.10 does not like my wife's elderly monitor

Tags: display, configuration, 18.10, ubuntu-studio

The monitor supports a native resolution of 1366x768. The Display configuration tool does not offer this resolution. The closest it comes is 1600x1200 or 1280x720.

These resolutions almost work. Aspect ratio is wrong for 1600x1200. If I could prevent the monitor from creating a big black square saying "Input not Supported" drifting across the screen it would be tolerable. 1280x720 seems to work but every couple minutes the screen blanks, blinks, and complains, then it sorta works for a few minutes again and repeats.

I really don't want to spend too much money on a used low res monitor or a big beautiful new high res monitor, when all I probably need is an obscure incantation in an obscure configuration file.